# Twitter count with the new Twitter update

Tags: twitter

As of today, its not possible to fetch tweet counts. You can read more here:
https://blog.twitter.com/2015/hard-decisions-for-a-sustainable-platform

So almost all scripts/plugins wont work anymore. What would be best alternative solution with the new twitter buttons/updated API, if such exists?

For example, is there a callback, once user successfully shares something? Because i could use that to increase tweet count in my own database? So saving them locally.

Comment: Am also curios, as I'd like https://meddelare.com/ to continue working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question based on findings:

For now its possible via http://opensharecount.com, they provide a drop-in replacement for the old private JSON URL based on searches made via the API (so you don't need to do all that work).

It's based on the REST API Search endpoints.